# Creating a custom GridView control that supports DynamicData

Tags: asp.net, .net-3.5, dynamic-data, custom-server-controls

I'm very disappointed in the built-in GridView control.

I wanted to make a simple data-entry web application, thinking Dynamic Data would save me time.

But it turns out that the GridView doesn't even support *basic* user interface scenarios such as inserting a new row.

Since the project I'm building will incorporate this scenario a lot, I'm considering creating my own grid-view control that does exactly what I need.

Is it difficult to develop a web control that supports dynamic data? Are there a lot of complicated hooks that rely on closed-source functionality in the .NET framework?

Or is it as simple as making the control data-bindable and having a DataSourceObject property?

Comment: What kind of Dynamic Data do you want? please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

The Gridview control is just a UI control, any inserting into that control would be done by the datasource bound to the gridview control.

Telerik makes their datagrid control DD-friendly - you could save yourself a lot of time just buying theirs if that is what you want.